# my android studio wont rebuild . Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: java, android

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows, try killing the java processes with task manager and doing a "Revalidate caches and restart" on android studio